# A non-open subset of the plane the intersection of which with any vertical and horizontal line is open in the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Please give an example of the plane subset which is not open set itself in usual euclidean $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ topology but for every line parallel to OX or OY its intersection with this line is open set in usual euclidean real line  topology.

Answer (score 3):

How about all of the plane *minus* an open line segment that is not parallel to either of the axes.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Seems to work great.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $Y^+$ be the positive $y$-axis, $Y^-$ the negative $y$-axis, $X^+$ the positive $x$-axis, and $X^-$ the negative $x$-axis. Find disjoint open nbhds of these four sets such that the closures of any two of these open sets intersect in one point, the origin. Then take the union of the four open sets together with the origin. I’ve left a specific example in the spoiler-protected block below.

> $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle:|y|<3|x|\}\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle:|x|<3|y|\}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $$A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x\notin \Bbb Q\vee y\ne x^2\}$$

Its complementary is not closed (its closure is the support of the curve $y=x^2$). However, for any straight line $R$, we have that $A\cap R=R\setminus C_R$, where $C_R$ is a set of almost two points.